# Is there any method to get the volume of something from images?

Tags: image-processing, volume

Consider some fluid fall which the flow rate can change, I wish to use images to get the volume of the part in the air(like the chocolate factory) , the images can be taken at multiple positions. What should I do? Like the process to follow or any algorithms that can solve some key problems.

Comment: How about showing us some sample images of the sort of thing you mean?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I will try to get it as early as possible, the company just came up with this question, I haven't got the material from them

Answer (score 0):

programming and image processing aside you'll need to consider the flow rate and the time it takes for the fluid to fall. So if the flow rate is x volume per time increment(e.g. x gallons/minute) and and the fall duration is y minutes then your volume in the air is x*y gallons.

Real world applications may vary depending on things like viscosity, temperature, wind, etc. You can also tackle this by figuring out the height and determining the time it takes something to fall by integrating To teach a program how to integrate you'll probably need to use Newtons Method.

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you! Actually I have done a project that used some equations and related inputs to generate the water swirl in Unity. Hopefully this project has some similarity with the old one.